# Javascript regex OR |

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, operators

I'm currently searching how to write correctly a regex for this application :
1 - A number without "." with a length of 1 to 5 digits
=> `/^(\d{1,5})$/`

2 - A number with "." with a length of 1 to 5 digits before the "." and 1 to 4 digits after the "."  or a number starting with "." with a length of 1 to 4 digits after the "."
=> `/^(\d{1,5})?\.?(\d{1,4})?$/`

I tried to use a or operator "|", but it doesn't work ;(
=> `/^(\d{1,5})?\.?(\d{1,4})?$|^(\d{1,5})$/`
I do not understand why, it's my first java script regex and i'm not sure to use well the "|" operator.

Following the answers I would like to obtain with **1** regex :

```
123 => ok
12345 => ok
123456 => not ok
12345.2156 => ok
123456.12 => not ok
12345.12345 => not ok
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Have a nice day.

Etienne

Comment: Surely then it's it's just a number with 0 to 5 digits `{0, 5}` before the `.`

Comment: What about `1234.12`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer 
{0, 5} before the . doesn't work
1234.12 => ok

Comment: `if ( number.length <= 5 ) {
  console.log(/^(\d{1,5})$/g.test(number));
} else {
  console.log(/^(\d{1,5})?\.?(\d{1,4})?$|^(\d{1,5})$/.test(number))
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both rules rolled in to one:

```
^\d{1,5}$|^\d{0,5}\.\d{1,4}$
```

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/vrM2CU/1)

Comment: Thank you very much Musefan, it's exactly what I expected!

Answer (score 3):

You could check the second part as optional.

```js
function check(v) {
    return /^(?=.)\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,4})?$/.test(v);
}

console.log(['', '.123', 123, 12345, 12345.2156, 123456, 123456.12, 12345.12345].map(check));
```

Comment: How about ".123" that should be ok

Comment: @musefan, no, according to "*A number with "." with a length of 1 to 5 digits before the "." and ...*"

Comment: And what does the rest of that exact sentence say? `"or a number starting with "." with a length of 1 to 4 digits after"`

Comment: i see no real number without a zero in front of it, there is no example from op.

Comment: Who said it needs to be a real number? I expect it's just input validation. Try enter `.123` in a calculator, you don't need to put the `0` at the start, it does it automatically. Point is, the OP has put it in the requirements and that is the only thing that matters, not your opinion on what a real number is or isn't

Comment: Only issue now, is that also matches an empty string... though it would be down to the OP to decide if that is ok or not...

Comment: Cool. I have never learned how positive lookaheads work, but it sure does work so that's what matters ;)

Comment: " I expect it's just input validation. Try enter .123 in a calculator, you don't need to put the 0 at the start, it does it automatically." 
Yes you're right Musefan

Comment: Thank you Nina,
It works to.
I didn't knew this way to perform a regex!

Answer (score 1):

`^(\d{1,5}|\d{1,5}\.\d{1,4}|\.\d{1,4})$` with a double | works just fine here https://regex101.com/r/jTVW2Z/1

Answer (score 0):

To use the or operator if you want to capture the value that matches you should wrap the regex in brackets `/(...)/` and split the reg with a pipe `/(...|...)/`.

```js
const checkNum = s => console.log(s, /^(\d{1,5}|\d{1,5}\.\d{4})*$/.test(s))

checkNum('55555.4444')
checkNum('88888')
checkNum('88888.22')
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use with `Array#split` . It's give the same result what you are expect from regex pattern.

```js
function check(a){
 var c= a.toString().split(".");
   return c[1]? ((c[0].length <= 5) && (c[1].length <= 4)) ? true : false : c[0].length <= 5 ? true : false;
}
console.log(check(123))
console.log(check(12345))
console.log(check(123456))
console.log(check(12345.2156))
console.log(check(123456.12))
console.log(check(12345.12345))
```

Comment: Thank you Prasad, another way to do it ;)